# Finally got Include working with child objects in Entity Framework 6.1

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6, repository-pattern, unit-of-work

I'm using a Generic Repository pattern, so it was crucial that I got this to work. I read in a couple of places online that Entity Framework will start to ignore Includes once the shape of the query changes. The fix was to move the Includes to the end of the query. This did not work for me. In fact, just the exact opposite is working. I moved the Where statement to the end of the Includes query.

Here is what I had.

```
public Task<List<T>> ItemsWithAsync(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate = null, params Expression<Func<T, object>>[] includeProperties)
        {
            IQueryable<T> query = null;
            if (predicate != null)
                query = _context.Set<T>().Where(predicate);
            else
                query = _context.Set<T>();

            foreach (var includeProperty in includeProperties)
            {
                query = query.Include(includeProperty);
            }

            return query.ToListAsync();
        }
```

Here is what now works for me.

```
public Task<List<T>> ItemsWithAsync2(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate = null, params Expression<Func<T, object>>[] includeProperties)
        {                
            var query = _context.Set<T>() as IQueryable<T>; // _dbSet = dbContext.Set<TEntity>()

            query = includeProperties.Aggregate(query, (current, property) => current.Include(property)).Where(predicate);

            return query.AsNoTracking().ToListAsync(); 
        }
```

The key for me was to move the .Where(predicate) to the end of the query that handles all the includedProperties.

In my case, this returns all the Parent objects and two Child objects for each record. Prior to this fix, I would get all the Parents objects and only 4 of the records would contain the Child objects.

Here is how I'm calling the methods.

```
using (var uow = _unitOfWorkFactory.Create())
            {

                return (await uow.OfferRepository.ItemsWithAsync2(o =>
                        o.Deleted == false
                        && o.StartDate <= clientDateTime
                        && o.ExpiryDate >= clientDateTime, o => o.Merchant, o => o.App)).ToList();
            }
```

Hope this helps! I searched for days and days. I never found the exact solution posted, which is why I posted it. Can anyone comment if this is an efficient way to solve the problem? Also, is the query.AsNoTracking actually needed? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here is what now works for me.

```
public Task<List<T>> ItemsWithAsync2(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate = null, params Expression<Func<T, object>>[] includeProperties)
        {                
            var query = _context.Set<T>() as IQueryable<T>; // _dbSet = dbContext.Set<TEntity>()

            query = includeProperties.Aggregate(query, (current, property) => current.Include(property)).Where(predicate);

            return query.AsNoTracking().ToListAsync(); 
        }
```

The key for me was to move the .Where(predicate) to the end of the query that handles all the includedProperties.

In my case, this returns all the Parent objects and two Child objects for each record. Prior to this fix, I would get all the Parents objects and only 4 of the records would contain the Child objects.

This also works with nested Child objects like o.Merchant.Locations.